# How do you make a Image View of a specific page?

Tags: 8, views, theming

I have a problem.

The thing is that I know that you can have a [Content Type] with an image [Field], and then you can create a [View] to display the image [Field] in each of the pages that are of the selected [Content Type].

However, (if I have a [Content Type] that is an image gallery), how can I create a view that only displays the gallery of one specific page? I mean, just one entry of a [Content Type].
For example, a services_list page of basic_page [Content Type].

The end goal I want to reach is a Slideshow of a gallery, and clicking that slideshow must send me to a specific page.
So if it was possible to assign a specific link to a slideshow, instead of using the option [Link to: Content] that would work too.

Comment: When you say `site`, to me, seems like you're trying to say "page"?

Comment: Uh, yeah! Sorry about that, I also forgot to mention that I'm using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

In the block's options there's a paginator setion that lets you include a "more" link, so it isn't exactly what I wanted, but I just put the page's link there, and it does work so I think I'll just leave it there.